# Editing Event in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, ekevent

This problem has been plaguing me for a week.

I have a `UISplitviewController` where both panels are always visible. In the master view, I have a list of calendar events, and when I select one, it loads the event into the detail view. I can edit the event fine, (the `EKEditEventViewController` is presented in the current context, showing up in front of the detail view only) but in iOS8, when you click the location cell, a new view controller is presented and searches for addresses that you type in. My problem comes when I dismiss this location selection view controller. When dismissed, the `EKEditEventViewController` behind it fills the whole screen (it appears partly behind the master view in the split view controller). When rotated, everything goes back to the way it should be.

Any idea why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
eventViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
```

did it for me, but this is what you've already done, as far I undestood.

Maybe putting the EKEventViewController in a UINavigationController smoothes out some other things, and setting there the current context could help.